Issue in integrating payment gateway from react native:
Problem Statement (React Native App)

When I click the 'Pay' button in React Native, the RazorPay page doesn't get triggered.
However, I've already configured the RazorPay key and order ID.

Error Received:
 LOG  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null]

Expected result:
we need to connect payment gateway from react native app
Tryouts
Working in ReactJS web application
React:
After clicking Recharge from Form Action it redirects to Node JS API with params.
Whereas rest api call is not working
Node:
NodeJS redirects to payment gateway
Payment completed
NodeJS then redirects to Web Application with success / failure msg


there can be a lot of reasons this is coming lemme share you a link to my react razorpay code which works even today just check it out and lemme know if it did
https://github.com/akashgreninja/React-RAZORPAY

I need a React Native payment gateway, not React. The React payment gateway is functional, but I require one specifically tailored for React Native. Currently, when I click the 'Pay' button in React Native, the RazorPay page fails to trigger.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
